# How to use Preview on Wordpress with Different Site Address and Wordpress Address

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I am using Laravel and Wordpress together so I can have Laravel front-end and Wordpress back-end.

I am running into one issue. I have Wordpress is a sub-directory in the public folder called /wordpress. I have changed the Wordpress URL to example.com/wordpress, but want to keep the Site URL as example.com. This makes it so the preview link says 'Sorry, you are not allowed to preview drafts.'

How can I stop this from happening even though my links need to be different? I want to handle previews with the front-end but I can't even get that far because wordpress thinks I don't have permisison!

Thanks!

Comment: The wordpress subdirectory is inside /public folder of laravel?

Comment: Yes it is. html/public/wordpress